# How to use both model propertie in single cshtml file in Strongly typed model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to write 2 @model in one cshtml file?
i want to use 2 model propertie in single page

```
@model Loek.Business.ViewModels.Companies.CurrentCompanyProfileViewModel.CompanyAddressViewModel2

@model Loek.Business.ViewModels.Companies.CurrentCompanyProfileViewModel.CompanyAddressViewModel2
@model Loek.Business.ViewModels.Companies.CurrentCompanyProfileViewModel
```

want to use both model propertie in single cshtml file

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is to make a new class with those two models as properties.
The Model View Controller scheme only allows one model.

```
public class CombinedCurrentCompanyProfileViewModel
{
   public CompanyAddressViewModel2 CompanyAddress { get; set; }
   public CurrentCompanyProfileViewModel CompanyProfile { get; set; }
}
```